# Tree searching algorithm

Tags: string, algorithm, search, graph, tree

I'm looking for suggestions on strategies for searching a tree-like data structure.

The structure is a tree where each element is a string, each branch is a period, and a path is the concatenation of several strings and periods starting at the root. The root and edges from the root are a special case where there is no string behind them.

So given the tree,

```
        {root}
      /       \
    A          X
  /   \      /
B       C   Y
```

Valid paths are the strings "A", "A.B", "A.C", "X", and "X.Y".

What we have is a set of strings that we need to search for in this tree and find the element that terminates each string. Not all strings in the set appear in the tree. We stop searching when we find all strings. We need to run this search several times but the trees may differ each time. The set of strings to search is the same each run though.

Currently we're using depth-first search, but this isn't very efficient if all strings fall under say the last branch under the root. I feel like there should be a better way of doing this.

What would be a good algorithm for doing this repeated search? Would it be possible to leverage multithreading here as well?

Comment: Are the children of each node always ordered alphabetically? Are the trees always balanced?

Comment: The trees are not balanced and the nodes are not ordered alphabetically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's an interesting problem; usually one would imagine a single tree being searched for a variable set of strings. Here the situation is reversed: the set of strings is fixed and the tree is highly variable.

I think that the best you can do is build a [trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) representing the set of strings. That way, you only have to search a tree once for any given prefix. (So, for the example strings you mentioned, you would only need to find the "A" prefix once and the "X" prefix once.) There are lots of trie data structures and algorithms for building them from a set of strings, but since that's a one-time operation for this problem, I wouldn't worry too much about the cost of this preprocessing.